# difference between openfeign or feign

Tags: spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

What is the difference between:

- spring-cloud-starter-openfeign (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign) and
- spring-cloud-starter-feign (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix) ?

I found this issue when I was trying to follow a tutorial using openfeign `@FeignClient(name=...)`. However, I was using feign, not openfeign, and this annotation was not the same.

Isn't it the same thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OpenFeign is the spiritual successor to Feign, originally provided by Netflix.  The projects name was changed when the original project was released to the community.  The correct dependency is `spring-cloud-starter-openfeign`.